# How much RP can I get at no cost

Tags: league-of-legends

At level 3, new summoners get a 400 RP bonus. Are there other ways to earn RP using such bonuses or promotions like the Tristana and Alistar free promos?

Comment: Youtubers who focus on Leagoe of Legends content often has Nasus skin give aways. But actually getting "free" rp is uncommon at most you get IP win boots if the servers are down.

Comment: So the 400 RP is the only bonus of its kind?

Comment: No but they are rare, so far I can confirm the answer, Major server stability problems, but even that is rare its mostly IP win boosts you get. I can not confirm the Christmas one though, Best you get are contests and giveaways on youtube for skins bot not actual RP.

Comment: I remember we got free RP if we had never been banned a while ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only RP you'll get for free is the 400 RP upon hitting level 3. Plus the 450 RP Riot usually hands out in December as a Christmas gift. The [new recruitment](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Refer_A_Friend) program also rewards heaps of RP and IP.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't for Christmas for being nice ?

Comment: That's absolutely correct! My bad, I assumed it was due to the server failures we experienced around that time. Edited my answer.

Comment: It may not be available till Dec., but more info is always useful. Can you also include the new summoner lvl 3 bonus here; if there are no better answers I can accept this later.

Comment: The RP giveaways seem to random, typically at least 1-3 a year, though I never notice why or when.

Answer (score 6):

The refer-a-friend program can get you 975 RP (and 5000 IP). Riot has cracked down on people making 10 alts and grinding them up to level 10 just for the free stuff, but it's a bit of a no-brainer if you happen to know 10 or more people who don't (yet) play LoL :)

For more info:

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Refer_A_Friend

Comment: You can get way more than 975RP via the referral program.  Just don't cheat!

Answer (score 0):

As others have said there isn't a true way to get free Riot Points other then the refer-a-friend bonus.

I have gotten some free Riot Points from a few giveaways people have hosted (mostly YouTube/stream related to grow their audience).

I recommend following [this website's](http://www.free-riot-points.com/) facebook page: They regularly post such giveaways for you to enter, the rest is luck though really.

Alternatively you can join a rewards site like PrizeRebel or GamerRewards and complete surveys for the RP but that takes a long time.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

There are no such things. You can take part on contests/givewaways or in smaller regional tourneys (they sometimes give away RP) but there is no real way to get RP for free